# RestKit: Connecting Non-Nested Relationships Using Foreign Keys - invalid attributes given for source entity

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map objects from two separate json files (while seeding an sqlite db with RestKit). The files are connected by a foreign id `file1Code`.

The structure looks like this:

File 1:

```
[ {
  "code": "1",
  "activ": false,
  "name": "Joe"
  },
  {
  "code": "2",
  "activ": false,
  "name": "John"
  }
]
```

File 2:

```
[
  {
  "code": 666000,
  "name": "Hausarzt",
  "file1Code": "1",
  "activ": false
  }
]
```

Entity for File 1 looks like this:

```
@interface File1Entity :  KeyTab
```

Entity for File 2 looks like this:

```
@interface File2Entity :  KeyTab
    @property (nonatomic, retain) File1Entitiy *file1Obj;

    // Transient
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *file1Code;
```

`KeyTab` (from which both inherit) looks like this:

```
@interface KeyTab :  NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * code;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * activ;
```

Now I am trying to use the "Connecting Non-Nested Relationships Using Foreign Keys" from the RestKit documentation found [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation).

I am using `addConnectionForRelationship` like this:

```
[file2EntityMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"file1Obj" 
    connectedBy:@{@"file1Code": @"code"}];
```

But get the error message "*Cannot connect relationship: invalid attributes given for source entity*" since `file1Obj` is a property and not an attribute.

Is this the right way to do this in RestKit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `file1Code` as a transient attribute on `File2Entity` and set it during the mapping. The foreign key connection is completed after the mapping so the original JSON is no longer available (hence the error that the data doesn't exist).

Comment: Actually, I already have `file1Code` as a transient attribute on `File2Entity`. But then it comes back to my [other open question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29670218/332248) on how I can intercept RestKit after the mapping and before the object gets stored so I can complete the relationship myself.

Comment: Foreign key mapping is how the relationship should be connected. If you have the attribute then you shouldn't see `invalid attributes given for source entity`.

Comment: First off: Thanks for your help. I tried to follow the guide that is titled "Connecting Non-Nested Relationships Using Foreign Keys" [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). And I think I have almost the same setup as the example has (I have two separate json files though).

Comment: The 2 files shouldn't matter, assuming you have a cache so the existing objects can be found, and that the 1 entities are processed and saved first. But, the error isn't that they couldn't be found, it's that the config is wrong and the specified connection parameters don't exist. So it's an entity / mapping issue. Show the full entity definitions - there should be an attribute for `file1Code`.

Comment: I have added the transient `file1Code` definition on `File2Entity`. This is how it used to work: The mapping was simply done by the transient file1Code. Then there was `didSeedObject `  and in there the real `File1Entity` object was loaded from the db (using the `file1Code`) and then that object was set as `file1Obj` and finally the `File2Entity` object was saved.